# If Html.RenderAction or Html.Action Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

So you have sections in the page, and if one section fails to render, rest of the page renders without a problem.  next request, everything works fine, or at least till it is fixed, all site doesnt go down. This was due to SOA.

I want to do the same thing via `Html.RenderAction` or `Html.Action`.

so if I have `@Html.RenderAction("Foo","Bar")` and if the call fails , i still want other sections on the page to render.

is this possible? if so how to do that? try/report/swallow?

Comment: Which technology did you use at this *biggest internet company*?

Comment: Wow. You ask a question, I try to dig into it and receive this kind of answer? I could expect this from a newbie, not from a user like you. Go back to Yahoo Answers, genius.

Comment: sorry if i hurt your feelings. thanks for downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question. Despite your rudeness, it's a good question and does not deserve a downvote. That's how SO works, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create helper methods, say `Html.TryRenderAction` and `Html.TryAction` to be called *instead* of `Html.RenderAction` and `Html.Action` respectively.

In turn, these should call the existing methods, but they should do so inside a `try` block that catches and logs the exceptions without giving up on the rest of the page.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a standard C# try/catch/finally block in a Razor .cshtml file.

```
@{
    try
    {
        Html.RenderAction("asdfasdf");   
    }
    catch
    {
        Output.WriteLine("<p>Failed to load asdfasdf</p>");
    }
}
```